# using a4j polling to update process status

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

So what I am trying to do is this:
I have a for loop that is generating files. Now this can take some time. For example it may take anywhere between 1-10 seconds to generate a file in my function let's say. However, I want to use a4j:poll every second to see how many files have been generated so far.

For the way I have done it, it appears that the poll waits until the for loop is finished executing even though its interval is 1 second. Is there some way to have the poll still check a variable's value every second even though the loop is still executing.

Am I using a4j:poll as intended? If not what is the correct way? Is there a better component to  use for this?

So here is my jsf code:

```
<h:form>
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
    <a4j:region id="pollregion" ajaxRendered="true">
         <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="1000" enabled="#{bean.pollEnabled}"
            render="poll,msg" />
    </a4j:region>
</<a4j:outputPanel>

<h:commandButton value="Generate Report" type="button"
    action="#{bean.generateReports}">
    <a4j:ajax event="click" render="poll,msg" />
</h:commandButton>

<a4j:outputPanel id="msg">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.status}" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
 </h:form>
```

And here is my bean:

```
private Integer totalCount;
private Integer processedCount;
private String last;
private String status;
private boolean pollEnabled = false;


public void generateReports() {
    reportStatus = "start";

    totalCount = getSelectedIds().length;
    processedCount = 0;

    pollEnabled = true;

    status = "Initiating report generation...";

    try{
        String[] ids = getSelectedIds();
        for(String id: rbIds){
            try
            {
              //generate report
            last = id;
            processedCount ++;
            status = "Processed " +  processedCount +" of " + totalCount + ". Last processed : " + last + ".";
            }catch(Exception e){
                displayException(e);
            }
        }

        status = "Successfully generated file.";
        pollEnabled = false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        displayException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the way JSF works, it will not let you access the variable while the loop is running.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that the poll is not executing every 1 second? In order to check that, you may 
put action attribute and an action method to see if its triggered every 1 second. It appears to me that your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
</<a4j:outputPanel>
```

The correct code is:

```
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

I was able to run your example with minor modifications (missing fields in the bean).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using: render="poll,msg" -> use: reRender="poll,msg"

The pool should now rerender every second.